# SwiftUI: present popover on iPhone?

Tags: swiftui, popover

I am looking at the Apple Reminders app and want to build the same pop over like view on iPhone. This the screen I am referring to:

[image]

So, I can present a popover like UI on an iPad using the popover modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // 1.
    @State var isPopoverPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        // 2.
        Button(action: {
            self.isPopoverPresented = true
        }) {
            Text("Some content")
        }
        // 3.
        .popover(isPresented: $isPopoverPresented) {
            Text("Popover is Presented")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
        }
    }
}
```

However when that code runs on an iPhone, the popover turns in a fullscreen modal coming up from the bottom.

I want to know if there is a native way to build a screen like the one shown in the Reminders app or, is that screen a custom View with custom layout logic on an iPhone?

Comment: As @aheze already answered, use Menu if you don’t need to customize much. With popover, you can build whatever view you like but you get a little arrow anchor. iPhone defaults to a sheet. To override this and show popover, use the .presentationCompactAdaption(.popover) modifier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for a [`Menu`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) ([`UIMenu`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenu) in UIKit). Note that it's iOS 14+ only.

Comment: Very nice. I’ll test it out. Thanks!